# Getting JSON value from PHP to Android

Tags: java, php, android, json, wordpress

I'm working on an Android web app and I need to get a value from a Php script depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

I have written the PHP script along with some JSON encoding but I can't get the value to android.

**PHP script**:

```
<?php

include 'wp-load.php';
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$id=$current_user->ID;
if ($id!=0) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print json_encode(array('user' => '1'));
} else {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print json_encode(array('user' => '0'));
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you let me the file location?

Comment: hype-strike.com/HypeStrike/checklogin.php

Comment: Include this file in functions.php and remove  wp-load.php code from your file and than check

Comment: how's that gonna help me get the value in android. i cant get the value in android. however the script works fine when i run it on a computer

Comment: Did not getting you pretty well here.. assuming that your user is logged in browser and you need that user id to the app API. Am i correct? Or you need user id which currently logged in to your app?

Comment: i need it in the app. i just need to see if user id is not equal to 0 that should mean that if user is using the app he is logged in but if he isnt then the value would be 0

Comment: So if i am not wrong you are trying to check that you user is logged in to the app or not.

Comment: exactly! but the thing is i ran a few codes to get the data from the php but even if the user is logged it the value of 0 is returned instead of his id

Comment: this is not possible. You can not do like this your app developer need to send the request with user id. according to my knowledge. If this is possible than why we need api for app? We can use other function of wordpress and we will get and update all the data directly.

Comment: well it is giving me an id if i check the script from browser then why not from mobile?

Comment: It is issue in mobile browser or in the mobile app?

Comment: i have tested on app

Comment: i wouldnt use php, unless you are paying for a a secure connection. use firebase / parse server and run cloud code.

Comment: can i use REST API to get the current user?

Comment: @ShwetaDhingana so you want that value 'user' = '0' or '1' in android application?